# How to call aspx page without opening it

Tags: asp.net, html, forms, http-post

I have a aspx page that I need to call without going directly on that page.
I have tried to make POST from form but it opens this action url in browser.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://mysite/actionpage.aspx">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `curl` if you're on a *nix system.

Here is a reference on how to post data to a page. The result will be returned through the command line.

[What is the curl command line syntax to do a post request?](https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request)

Here is the syntax for reference:

`curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/resource.cgi`

or

`curl -F "fileupload=@filename.txt" http://example.com/resource.cgi`

Answer (score 1):

If jQuery is allowed to use in your case, You may use jQuery ajax to call that page

```
  $("form").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post("yoursecondpage",function(data){
       //do whatever with the response from that page
     });    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via ajax.
For example, if you add a script reference to jQuery things will get much easier, and you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function postIt()
   {
     $.post( 
       "http://mysite/actionpage.aspx" 
        , function(data)
        {
          // data was returned from the server 
          alert("data posted in the background");
        } );
   }
 </script>
```

The processing you be done via background.

Your final HTML woul be :

```
  <form method="POST" action="http://mysite/actionpage.aspx">     

       <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="postIt();" />     
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested , but looks like you are navigating to .aspx means server page, i.e. you need to use **runat="Server"** in your tags like this

Comment: I think this is not the case. Adding it will still making post backs to happen.